# Visualize logistic regression fit with stats models

Tags: python, statistics, logistic-regression, statsmodels

Straightforward question, really. I just fit a logistic regression to some data:

```
logit = sm.Logit(df.flow2, df.latency_condition)
result = logit.fit()

print(result.summary())
```

Which yields:

```
                          Logit Regression Results                           
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                  flow2   No. Observations:                 5930
Model:                          Logit   Df Residuals:                     5929
Method:                           MLE   Df Model:                            0
Date:                Mon, 10 Sep 2018   Pseudo R-squ.:                 -0.3009
Time:                        21:18:35   Log-Likelihood:                -3927.8
converged:                       True   LL-Null:                       -3019.2
                                        LLR p-value:                       nan
=====================================================================================
```

I now would like to plot this result on top of my data points, but I have no idea how to do this. I used seaborn to plot a regression:

```
sns.lmplot(x="latency_condition", logistic=True, y="flow2", data=df)
plt.show()
```

I know lmplot uses statsmodels, but I'm not sure how I fit the model was exactly the same as how lmplot does it. Also, I just want to be able to plot the complete logistic regression curve (from y=1 to y=0). So how do I plot this statsmodels result? Alternative approaches are welcome.

**Edit:**

Daniel below gave me a straightforward solution, and I believe it's correct. I'm not sure what the difference is between fitting logistic regression my way, and what lmplot does. I'm guessing I should mirror my x-axis, or fit a different curve, due to the downward slope of my data?

This is what lmplot gives me:

[image: lmplot]

And this is the result of the regression:

[image]

Comment: You can try to .predict() on np.arange(df.flow2.min(),.df.flow2.max(),1) if df.flow2 is your independent variable, and plot the result of the predictions.

Comment: You mean use it on df.latency_condition, as that is my independent variable here? I don't know how to use this predict function with the results of my fit, TBH.

Comment: You are correct, Logit constructor considers the second variable as the independent variable, which is odd, [documentation here](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Logit.html). Yes in this case you should call logit.predict() on an array of evenly spaced values between the min and max values of the independent variable, and then plot the predictions obtained in this manner.

Answer (score 4):

Ok so I tested a solution, and it works. Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

HOW_MANY = 10
x = np.random.randn(HOW_MANY)

y = np.linspace(0,1,HOW_MANY)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x,'y':y})
logit = sm.Logit(df['y'],df['x']).fit()

pred_input = np.linspace(x.min(),x.max(),HOW_MANY)
predictions = logit.predict(pred_input)
plt.scatter(df['x'],df['y'])
plt.plot(pred_input,predictions,c='red')
plt.show()
```

If you want to extend the red curve further towards right or left, just pass a pred_input array that spans a larger range.

> I know lmplot uses statsmodels, but I'm not sure how I fit the model was exactly the same as how lmplot does it.

You don't have any guarantee, since sns.lmplot() will fit a new regression if you call it like you suggest. You want to plot the prediction space of the Logit constructor, by feeding it a mock input vector that ranges across the space of all possible inputs, or as much of it as feasible. 10/100 values is a good number.

Comment: I think you did exactly what I asked, and my mistake starts earlier than that. I'll update the original post to clarify what I mean.